# Python module attributes not recognised in ExternalEvaluate

Tags: external-calls, python

I have Python installed and running properly. I have a file called `test.py` with contents

```
c = 5
```

When I go to the file's directory and type `import test` followed by `test.c` at the Python prompt in Bash, it returns `5`, as expected. When in Wolfram|One I execute `ExternalEvaluate["Python", "1+2"]`, it returns `3`. So far, so good. But when I set the directory to the file's directory and execute

```
s = StartExternalSession["Python"];
ExternalEvaluate[s, "import test"];
ExternalEvaluate[s, "test.c"]
```

it yields a `Failure` with tag "EvaluationFailure" and message "Exception Thrown: AttributeError". Inspection of the `InputForm` of the `Failure` reveals the line "AttributeError: module 'test' has no attribute 'c'".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some sleuthing around the internet, I found the problem. The current working directory is not added to Python's path variable. So you have to do this:

```
s = StartExternalSession["Python"];
ExternalEvaluate[s, "sys.path.insert(1, '')"];
ExternalEvaluate[s, "import test"];
ExternalEvaluate[s, "test.c"]
```

the second line of which adds the current directory to the path. On my system, using `sys.path.append('')` in place of `sys.path.insert(1, '')` didn't work, apparently because there was another `test` module somewhere else in the path. I read in a few places a recommendation to use `sys.path.insert(1, '')` rather than `sys.path.insert(0, '')`.

Comment: Fantastic! This has just saved me...

Comment: @wilsnunn Glad to have been of service, sir/madam.

Comment: Hmm. I have the same problem. I cannot import from the local directory. I checked with `os.getcwd()` that the directory is set correctly. Unfortunately adding `ExternalEvaluate[s, "sys.path.insert(1, '')"];` does not seem to help.