# ExternalEvaluate Python: Cannot import local file

Tags: python, external-calls

I am trying to use `ExternalEvaluate` for a Python session. For some reason I cannot import a file from there that I can import successfully when I call python some other way. I already verified that the current working directory in python is the correct one. I also added the directory to the path in two ways because it solved a similar issue here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/185587/45020. For example the following outputs the correct directory (twice) and indeed the file I am trying to load is listed in the `os.listdir()` output.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
s = StartExternalSession["Python"];
ExternalEvaluate[s, "import os"];
ExternalEvaluate[s, "os.getcwd()"]
ExternalEvaluate[s, "os.chdir(" <> Directory[] <> ")"];
ExternalEvaluate[s, "sys.path.insert(1, '')"];
ExternalEvaluate[s, "os.getcwd()"]
ExternalEvaluate[s, "sys.path.insert(os.getcwd())"];
ExternalEvaluate[s, "os.listdir()"]
ExternalEvaluate[s, "import filenameWithoutPYExtension"]
```

I still get the `no module named 'filenameWithoutPYExtension'` error though.

Answer (score 5):

In Mathematica 12.2 `Directory[]` returns the `Documents` folder in windows, instead of that use `NotebookDirectory[]` to get your notebook directory. In python, for importing files from unknown directories you can use `sys` library:

```
s = StartExternalSession["Python"];

ExternalEvaluate[s, 
 "import sys;sys.path.append(" <> 
  ExportString[NotebookDirectory[], "PythonExpression"] <> ")"]

ExternalEvaluate[s, "import filenameWithoutPYExtension"]

DeleteObject[s];
```

Also see [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193988/difficulty-with-externalevaluate/241046#241046).

Another point is you can use `;` to run multiple lines in python:

```
ExternalEvaluate["Python", "import os;os.getcwd()"]

(*Out: "C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Documents" *)
```

While passing strings to python directly, having single `\` is problematic, for this reason, I use `ToString[..., InputForm]` which replace `\` with `\\`. Using `ExportString[..., "PythonExpression"]` is a better option so I replace it with that.

Comment: Of course `Directory[]` returns the current (MMA) working directory, which might by Documents by default. In this case I had set it to `NotebookDirectory[]` so I will edit the question to clarify this. I do think you give the correct answer when you say that I should run `ExternalEvaluate[s, 
 "import sys;sys.path.append(" <> 
  ToString[NotebookDirectory[], InputForm] <> ")"]`. So perhaps you can explain why I had to add the full path like this.